# File upload with django-profiles

Tags: django, django-profiles

I'm using the django-contrib package [django-profiles](http://www.bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-profiles/wiki/Home), and everything is working great - my only issue is that I would like the form to upload a file (for an avatar), unfortunately - the form does not upload the file.

Has anyone successfully managed to get file uploads working with django-profiles? I want to avoid having to set up a seperate upload view just for the avatar?

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your template add enctype="multipart/form-data" in form tag. Example:

```
<form method="post" action="." enctype="multipart/form-data">
```